# How do I add JavaScript to a site?

Tags: javascript, theming

How can I add JavaScript and CSS to my site?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722) guide provides the information to add JavaScript to Drupal. The techniques presented there apply to both [themes](https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7) and [(custom) modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules):

- Add a `scripts[] = somescript.js` to your module or theme's `.info`
  file
- Use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in your module or theme's code
- Use the [`#attached['js']`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x@#attached) property in a [Form API](https://drupal.org/node/37775) or [renderable array](https://drupal.org/node/930760).

Note that Drupal already include jQuery, jQuery UI and a bunch of other libraries so you don't, and shouldn't, add them yourself. Instead you should use [`drupal_add_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7) or the `#attached['library']` property.

The [Working with CSS](https://drupal.org/node/341246) guide provides the information to add CSS to Drupal. Again, the techniques presented there apply to both themes and (custom) modules. With an exception: addition of style sheets from an `.info` files only works for a theme and not a module.

- Add `stylesheets[all][] = somestylesheet.css` to a theme's `.info` file.
- Use [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) from module or theme's code.
- Use `#attached[css]` property in a From API or renderable array.

Comment: do I need to enable php filter? And where do I add the js. Is it the body section with script tag? like <script></script> I need a simple example to get started. Very basic. Pls

Comment: You don't add CSS or JavaScript as content of your site, so you don't do it when editing your content. If you need page specific JavaScript or CSS, you can do it from your theme's page preprocess hook.

Adding styles (CSS) or behaviors (JavaScript) to your site should be done from code, not from the Web UI. This is way more maintenable and scalable and avoid you, or others, many headaches when updating the site later.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your js file in your theme folder and add this js file to drupal by using `drupal_add_js()` in template.php [preprocess functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7).