# Add JS to Drupal node form

Tags: nodes, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add JavaScript to my Drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-to-add-javascript-to-my-drupal-site)

I'm writing some javascript for my content type so that when new content is created, while inputting for one field, the other fields would automatically populate and update.

I was told to use `drupal_add_js()` to include the js file, but I'm still a bit new to Drupal. Can anyone walk me through the whole process?

Like where to put the js file, where to tell drupal to include the js file, how can I target the content field in js?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't use google before ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584405/adding-js-to-a-drupal-node-form

Comment: Also please choose Drupal version in tags

Comment: @drupality There isn't the need to add a version tag; it's enough the OP reports for which Drupal version is interested.