# Auto Refresh Div Using jQuery from 5 Seconds to Zero

Tags: javascript

How to create a countdown counter in Drupal 7 that says:

Your download will start in 5 seconds...

During page load and it countdown the number to 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

And change the value to "our download will start shortly... "

When finished?

Comment: This is more of a vanilla JavaScript question, and should really be on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/) demo...That is all you need...

Also look at [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tFw2a/) and [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/ysilvestrov/bUZd8/1/)...

To learn how to include script in Drupal look at [THIS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12855/14487) answer...

Comment: You're welcome...enjoy... ;)