# How to execute javascript within drupal for a specific field on a specific page?

Tags: javascript, forms

**The Initil question**
I have a input field which should activate a function on the onfocus javascript event on a field on the user page.

Step 1 
Add code to a custom module:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(totalname(){
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.background = "yellow";
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The currently HTML is:

```
<input type="text" id="fullname"><br>
```

And it should become like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" onfocus="totalname()"><br>
```

How to get the onfocus=... inside the input element?
Is the custom code ok?

### **Addition to this question.**

Thxs you so much for all the comments. Based on that I learned i few things more so I now understand what the real question should be.

To understand how I can executed javascript code in a certain field on a certain page in drupal.

I assumed this was needed by a callback but this is not encoured according to @Jimmy so I'm trying to understand the way it should be according to drupal standards. Also I was suprised that no change in HTML was needed as @Adrian gave an example. I could not get it run because of the typo :-( So in mean time I made another solution.

The  script is basicly just a real time concatination of first, middle and last name into a fullname field.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

        function setFullName() {
            var nameParts = [document.getElementById("edit-field-voornaam-und-0-value").value,  
                             document.getElementById("edit-field-tussenvoegsel-und-0-value").value, 
                             document.getElementById("edit-field-achternaam-und-0-value").value],
                name = nameParts.join(" ").trim();

            document.getElementById("edit-field-naam-und-0-value").value = name;
        }

        var fields = [document.getElementById('edit-field-voornaam-und-0-value'), 
                      document.getElementById('edit-field-tussenvoegsel-und-0-value'), 
                      document.getElementById('edit-field-achternaam-und-0-value')];

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fields[i].addEventListener("keyup", setFullName);
        }


  });
})(jQuery);
```

So this is working and I put it in a custom module.

I still do not understand how I should be if I rewrite the code following the example of @adrian as this code is still executed on every page and not a specific page.

Thank you for learning !! and not using the correct words. I'm not native english ...

Comment: Please note that adding callback function in attributes is not encouraged in Drupal project.

Comment: Ok, what is the correct way for implementing this in drupal?

Comment: Check @AdrianCidAlmaguer answer

Comment: I edit the answer, take a look at the end

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Please don't edit random stuff into the question in an attempt to make it on topic - the OP didn't say anything even remotely related to the edit you made. This is a plain JS question, so will always be off topic here.

Comment: It is not plain js question as I do not understand how to activate from drupal

Comment: I don't know what that means @Justme - the question you've asked its about Javascript functionality, not about Drupal's use of javascript. Specifically: _How to get the onfocus=... inside the input element? Is the custom code ok?_. That's clearly not about Drupal. If you were asking how to add javascript to a page, we'd have pointed you to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), and/or closed this as one of the many duplicates that ask the same thing. [This one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-to-add-javascript-to-my-drupal-site), for example

Comment: @Justme I think that you need to edit your question with more additional information about your really problem

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Ah sorry - that's entirely my fault, I thought I'd read every comment but I obviously missed one

Comment: @adrian, 100% agree !!!

Comment: @Justme In this case edit your question please, maybe we're missing something.

Comment: and finally do you found the solution?

Comment: Hi Adrian, no, it is stil running on every page. I have on my todolist to try to get it on a specific page with the help of module js injector.

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery:

```
//Making a focus over the element
(function ($) {
    $('#fullname').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("color");
      })
      .focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("color");
      });
})(jQuery);
```

Your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fullname"><br>
```

Your CSS:

```
.color {
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

**EDIT:**
To attach the js code to your page you can use `#attached` in a renderable array (this is the recommended way). I think that you should read: [How to add jQuery UI libraries to a page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2221855).

Comment: Adrian, I'm trying to learn and I understand the answer. But I need lots more of javascript to execute around this element. Therefore the question is how to inject JS instead of how to make a the field yellow :-)

Comment: @Justme there is an error in Adrian's answer. should be $(`'#fullname')`

Comment: ok understand that typo but don't understand the code :-( What is the general code to activate a js function (totalname on element fullname?

Comment: I think @NoSssweat is right. However, the nature of the suggested edit by Jimmy Ko is a bit difficult to judge as a reviewer. Therefor I think Adrian is the only one who should decide to yes or no accept that edit. If needed, perform a rollback to the prior version (and apply any other/similar fixes where appropriate). Good luck!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens would you mind telling me what is the difficult point? :)

Comment: Please don't edit code in people's answers @JimmyKo, you don't know what their intention was. Thanks :)

Comment: @Clive fine. I thought it is a obvious error. BTW, you changed it back :)

Comment: Yeah I know, just caught that @JimmyKo ;) You're almost definitely right, but we tend not to 2nd-guess with code. Cheers

Comment: @JimmyKo : glad you asked! "I" think your suggested edit made sense, and is correct, and I approved it, right? However this was your 2nd suggestion (same content), after your first (identical) suggestion was also approve "by me", but which was then "rejected" by 2 other reviewers (so that the first suggestion verdict = rejected). However, the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)  (oeps ...) of this site here (which I did not invent) do not allow such edits (only the OPer can apply such changes ... I think). So that is why "I" believe only Adrian in the end should decide. OK?

Comment: Hm, I just saw Clive's note (and rollback), which seems to confirm my perception also. I trust later on Adrian will seriously consider Jimmy's edit again (or maybe extend his answer to further clarify). PS to @JimmyKo : any other edit suggestions (without changing code ...)?

Comment: @JimmyKo thanks for the edit, I just see the error now

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think that I made the error because I copy the code from one site that I made and I don't see the problem between the id and the class element.