# Datepicker widget. How can I add some variable javascript code from my module to configure the date popup calendar?

Tags: 7, javascript, datetime

I need to personalize some settings in the date popup calendar in a date field.
This is the documentation for the popup calendar used in the Drupal date field:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I would to configure for example, the minDate property, to set a minimum selectable Date, according the documentation this is the code:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

But... How and where do I type it in a custom module? It looks javascript, but I don't know how to make this code work for my date form element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it with `#datepicker_options`, e.g.:

```
$form['date'] = [
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  // ...
  '#datepicker_options' => [
    'minDate' => 0,
  ],
];
```

Comment: Clive, I think your code is good for adding a new form element. What is the code to add the property in an existent form element?

Comment: Very similar, just find where the element you want to change is in the form array and use something like `$form['foo']['#datepicker_options'] = ...`

Comment: I have tried multiple #datepicker_options in different places and it doesn't work on my popup calendar. I want to try with javascript. How can I add the javascript code programmatically from my module?. I need programmatically because the property I have to change is a variable value in my specific use case.

Comment: Adding/managing JS is covered at length in [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7); that page should everything you need from the sounds of your requirements, but if not try searching this site. For example http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-to-add-javascript-to-my-drupal-site has some good supplementary info. Personally I'd be tempted to persevere with the form alter approach, it's likely you just haven't found the right array element yet. Also: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy

Comment: What would be the code to add my above javascript, inline, only injected to my form element datepopup, from my custom module?

Comment: All that information is in the above link, where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: It's difficult for me to explain. The Javascript code I put above is extracted from the documentation of jquery ui date popup calendar used for Drupal. With that code I intent to disable some days before a specific day in calendar popup. That is my objetive. My doubts are: 1) This code will work for my form element, or do I need to modify some on it to affect my element?. If so, What do I need to modify?. And 2)How would be the code to add in my .module file to put this javascript code inside?. Ex: drupal add js, drupal.behavior, echo "<script>inline js</script>". (I have read your links)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53525/discussion-between-bunset-and-clive).

Comment: In this code:
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ 
minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) 
});
Do I need to change $(".selector"), for another word instead of selector to attack my form element?

Comment: Yes, but I can't tell you what that is you need to inspect the code and see what classes your theme is attaching to the input for you to target